# How can i use 2 QTimer? One is for counting and the other one is displaying

Tags: c++, qt, timer, qtimer

I want to Timer with c++ using Qt. I have one timer in my code, but the time display on the screen is slow. timer -> start(500) must update  every 20 seconds I guess.

I want to use 2 timers for it. One is for update and count the time, the other timer will display on the screen. How can I do that, I would be very happy if you can help

Here is my code:

```
#include "mainwindow.h"
#include "ui_mainwindow.h"
#include <QTimer>
#include <QPushButton>


QTimer *timer = new QTimer();
QTimer *timer2 = new QTimer();

MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent)
    : QMainWindow(parent)
    , ui(new Ui::MainWindow)
{
    ui->setupUi(this);

    connect(timer,
            SIGNAL(timeout()),
            this,
            SLOT(functionstart())
            );    
}


void MainWindow::functionStart()
{    
    int count;   
    count = ui->lcdNumber->value();
    count++;
    ui->lcdNumber->display(count);
}

MainWindow::~MainWindow()
{
   delete ui;    
}

void MainWindow::on_pushButton_clicked()
{    
    if(timer->isActive()){
        timer->stop();
        ui->pushButton->setText("Start");
    }
    else {
        timer->start(500); 
        ui->pushButton->setText("Stop");
    }
}
```

Comment: Create two timers, connect to their respective timeout() signals and do whatever you want to do in the called slots.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you start a timer like this **timer -> start(500)** it will timeout every 500ms (0.5 sec) so if you want a timer with 20 second timeout, you can start it with **timer -> start(20000)**.
Now if you want another timer for updating display you can start your timer2 with period that you like and connect it to another slot to update UI like this:

```
#include "mainwindow.h"
#include "ui_mainwindow.h"
#include <QTimer>
#include <QPushButton>

QTimer *timer = new QTimer();
QTimer *timer2 = new QTimer();

MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent)
    : QMainWindow(parent)
    , ui(new Ui::MainWindow)
{
    ui->setupUi(this);
    connect(timer, SIGNAL(timeout()), this, SLOT(functionStart()));
    connect(timer2, SIGNAL(timeout()), this, SLOT(updateDisplay()));
}

MainWindow::~MainWindow()
{
    delete ui;
}

void MainWindow::functionStart()
{
    count += 1;
}

void MainWindow::updateDisplay()
{
    ui->lcdNumber->display(count);
}

void MainWindow::on_pushButton_clicked()
{

    if(timer->isActive() & timer2->isActive())
    {
       timer->stop();
       timer2->stop();
       ui->pushButton->setText("Start");
    }
    else
    {
       timer->start(1000);
       timer2->start(20000);
       ui->pushButton->setText("Stop");
    }
}
```

I moved the count definition to MainWindow header file to keep it value.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. When i run the code you suggest, the counter is not refreshing. Where could I be wrong

Comment: It will update every 20 second, change the value to whatever you want on on_pushButton_clicked()

Comment: I understand, I changed but it does not change. The value on the lcddisplay is always 0

Comment: What is your desired period for updating? and how long do you want to update the count? every second?

Comment: the number on the display should update 20 times per second.

Comment: so change the timer2 value to 50. what about the count? did you move it to header file?

Comment: It can be synchronous with timer2. There is no rule for it. After all this changes, what should i do if there is no change on the display?

Comment: private slots:
    void on_pushButton_clicked();

private:

    Ui::MainWindow *ui;

    int Count;

Comment: check your connect function and place some debugging stuff. if you have any error place it here

Comment: In header file, where should i placed the count?

Comment: In private members define it with lower case letters.

Comment: i did everything right but still doesn't work :(

Comment: it gives an error at main.cpp with QApplication a(argc, argv);

Comment: I add a comment

Answer (score 0):

I added qDebug section for it. When I do this , I can see on the console that it refresh 20 times in a second. But there is still no changes on display. Here is my code

```
#include "mainwindow.h"
#include "ui_mainwindow.h"
#include <QTimer>
#include <QPushButton>
#include <QDebug>

 QTimer *timer = new QTimer();

 QTimer *timer2 = new QTimer();





MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent)
: QMainWindow(parent)
, ui(new Ui::MainWindow)
{
ui->setupUi(this);


    connect(timer, SIGNAL(timeout()), this, SLOT(functionStart()));
    connect(timer2, SIGNAL(timeout()), this, SLOT(updateDisplay()));


}

MainWindow::~MainWindow()
{
delete ui;
}



void MainWindow::functionStart()
{

count += 1;

}

void MainWindow::updateDisplay()

 {


 ui->lcdNumber->display(count);

qDebug() << "asadsf";

 }


void MainWindow::on_pushButton_clicked()
{


    if(timer->isActive() & timer2->isActive())
        {
           timer->stop();
           timer2->stop();
           ui->pushButton->setText("Start");
        }
        else
        {
           timer->start(40);
           timer2->start(50);
           ui->pushButton->setText("Stop");
        }



}
```

Comment: Print count value with qDebug and check it

Comment: It starts to count with 25984769. There is still no change on display. It shows only 0. By the way, why didn't counting starts from 0

Comment: Because you didn't set an initial value for count. Use int count = 0;